# Does docker compose exec <service> <command> ignore the entrypoint?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I cannot find any answer to my question and I can't make the entrypoint run when using `docker compose exec`. I'm using a custom entrypoint in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yml
version: "3.8"

services:
  php:
    image: php:8-fpm
    entrypoint: ./docker-php-entrypoint.sh
    command: ["php-fpm"]
```

The `./docker-php-entrypoint.sh` is executable and it echo something:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

echo "Hello World!"

exec "$@"
```

Since `docker compose exec` executes commands for a running service:

```
docker compose up -d
docker compose exec php ls
```

The echo "Hello World!" is visible when the container starts, but not when executing `exec php ls`.

Is supposed to work this way? In essence, can the entrypoint be used to run arbitrarty script before any command is invoked in the container?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_exec/#:~:text=Creates%20containers%20for%20a%20service.&text=Receive%20real%20time%20events%20from%20containers.&text=Execute%20a%20command%20in%20a%20running%20container.,-docker%20compose%20images&text=Force%20stop%20service%20containers. your container is not even running is it?

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 it is running, I'll update the question thaks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how the `exec` command works. It allows you to run a command in an already running container. It would make no sense to execute the entrypoint as part of that, as it might run a long running process or similar, and never return, or exit, an then never actually run the command you wanted to.
Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It makes almost sense. In the context of run, in fact, it is executed i.e. `docker compose run --rm php ls`. But if I update the script it still uses the old script. Do you know why?

Comment: `docker compose` is a helper abstraction over docker. What `run` is doing is interacting with an already existing service (container). Probably you need to update the container image, if that's where the script you're referring to is coming from. Since you're passing the `--rm` flag, it's already deleting the container, so hence it's highly likely that your container image is outdated.

Answer (score 2):

You've described the "entrypoint wrapper" pattern: in fact, you can use an entrypoint script to do any setup you need to do, and then the `exec "$@"` will run the main container command.

A container normally only runs a single command, but conversely, a container isn't especially expensive.  If you

```bash
docker-compose run php ls
```

it will create a second container and launch its entrypoint, passing the alternate command `ls` as the command arguments to it.  This can be a good way to debug an image, especially if it doesn't start.

You shouldn't frequently need `docker{,-compose} exec`.  If you do use it, as you note, it doesn't run the container entrypoint a second time, but instead just runs the command you give it.  The other important note this pattern is that the `exec` environment does not inherit from the entrypoint process at all.  For example, if your entrypoint script sets up environment variables from a dynamic source, `docker-compose exec php env` won't show those variables.

Since the entrypoint is just a script (or another program) if you do need to use `exec` you can explicitly specify it, if you actually need to run it.

```bash
docker-compose exec php ./docker-php-entrypoint.sh ls
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips helping me debugging the image.